# PHPUnit tests real example

Tags: php, email, tdd, phpunit, wrapper

I've created a [mail](http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php) wrapper class. I know that there are lots of libraries to send e-mails but i want to learn TDD... So, I've created some tests and i have some code. Now I can set the email address on constructor and validate it... if the email address is wrong, an exception raise up. The email address is the only one required field... I don't have sets and gets because user will setup all email data on constructor.

Now, i'm going to write the send tests. I don't know how to start it. How could i test if  the values are there (subject, mail body, headers) if i don't want to have setters and getters? How could I test if an email could be sent?

Real world TDD examples are hard to me. I've tried to learn about it, i've read lots of things but i cannot test real code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you linked to the mail function, the call to `mail` is likely hardcoded into your code. So have a look at

- http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html

Install the [testhelper extension](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers) and mock the call to `mail`. Then have the mock validate that it got called with the correct values when your wrapper's send method is called, e.g. define a custom mail function somewhere:

```
function mail_mock()
{
    $allThatWasPassedToTheFunction = func_get_args();
    return $allThatWasPassedToTheFunction;
}
```

Then in your `send()` test, do something like

```
public function testSendReceivesExpectedValues()
{
    // replace hardcoded call to mail() with mock function
    rename_function('mail', 'mail_orig');
    rename_function('mail_mock', 'mail');

    // use the wrapper
    $testClass = new MailWrapper('foo@example.com');
    $results = $testClass->send();

    // assert the result
    $this->assertSame('foo@example.com', $results[0]);
    $this->assertSame('Default Title', $results[1]);
    $this->assertSame('Default Message', $results[2]);
}
```

Note that the above assumes your send function will return the result of the `mail()` call.

In general, you will always try to substitute an external subsystem, like sendmail or a database or the filesystem with a [Mock or a Stub](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TheDifferenceBetweenMocksAndStubs), so you can concentrate on testing your own code in isolation of the external subsystem. You dont need to test that `mail` actually works.

Also see http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 2):

In a pure unit test, you don't really test whether a real email has been sent, but rather whether the appropriate programming unit (the `mail` function in this case) has been called. I don't really know how to test whether the `mail` function really works as I don't have in depth knowledge of how emailing works under the hood. So, I'll just write how I'd do the unit test.

You can have your class constructor accept an optional argument, a function that does the real work of actually sending the email. By default, it will be the `mail` function, but in your test setup, you provide your special function that will actually checks the correct subject, body and headers are present.

The test:

```
<?php

class EmailerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testMailFunctionIsCalledWithCorrectArguments()
  {
    $actualSubject, $actualBody, $actualHeaders;
    $mailFunction = function ($subject, $body, $headers)
        use (&$actualSubject, &$actualBody, &$actualHeaders) {
      $actualSubject = $subject;
      $actualBody = $body;
      $actualHeaders = $headers;
    };

    $emailer = new Emailer($options, $mailFunction);
    $emailer->send();

    $this->assertEquals('Expected subject', $actualSubject);
    $this->assertEquals('Expected body', $actualBody);
    $this->assertEquals('Expected headers', $actualHeaders);
  }
}
```

And the class under test:

```
<?php

class Emailer
{
  public function __construct($options, $mailFunction = 'mail')
  {
    $this->subject = $options->subject;
    $this->body = $options->body;
    // etc.
    $this->mailFunction = $mailFunction;
  }

  public function send()
  {
    // find out $subject, $body, $headers, and then...

    call_user_func_array($this->mailFunction, array(
      $subject,
      $body,
      $headers
    ));
  }
}
```

It's some sort of pseudo-code, because I've left some of the values for you to complete or implement. The main point is that you should supply test doubles for the collaborators of the class you're testing.

In this case it's just a function (I've made use of some PHP 5.3) features, but it could be an object instance that you'd pass to the class under test.

Answer (score 0):

I think the class should performs validation for email, subject and other information so I suggest this should be separated to the functions.

When you have the private validation function that must return specific result then you can write the assertion to test it.

[this article](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/881-Testing-Your-Privates.html) might be useful.

I'm very new to TDD too and I choose to depend on the IDE (Netbeans) to help me understand this process.

hope this help :)

Comment: How does Netbeans do that? Thank you.

Comment: It has PHPUnit feature integrated also the code-completion that list the PHPUnit test functions. It isn't do all the task for you it just provide the facility to do it easier. Try this article http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html